# How can I add a character at cursor?

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I'm trying to add a row of 'Hotkeys' to Code Mirror. For a normal `<textarea id=code>` I could do: 
`insertAtCursor(code,'hello')`
With:

```
function insertAtCursor(textArea,text) 
{
    if (textArea.setSelectionRange)
    {
        textArea.value = textArea.value.substring(0,textArea.selectionStart) + text + textArea.value.substring(textArea.selectionStart,textArea.selectionEnd) + textArea.value.substring(textArea.selectionEnd,textArea.value.length);
    } 
    else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) 
    {
        textArea.focus();
        var range = document.selection.createRange();

        range.text = text + range.text;
    }
}
```

How could I do this with a CodeMirror instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a small example where you want to insert an extra character for autocompletion. If user starts typing a ( you want to add an extra ) and set the cursor one place back so he can directly continue to type.

```
editor.on('keypress', function(cm,e){
  console.log("keypress: "+e.charCode);
  if(e.charCode === 40) { //check for ( and autocomplete with ) while placing cursor inside ()
      e.preventDefault(); //ignore this key
      editor.replaceSelection("()"); //replace with ()
      editor.setCursor(editor.getCursor().line,editor.getCursor().ch-1); //set cursor back one position
      return false;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function insertAtCursor(instance, text) {
  instance.replaceSelection(text);
}
```

Comment: Works now, but when ever I add something it is selected. Any fixes?